# State is not showing anything on webpage but showing in console React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started creating a web app like Facebook messenger in React.js. I'm getting some input from user and then using state and it is working perfectly. I'm showing that input in console that is also working perfectly as it ca be seen in [screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMZqb.png)

the problem is i'm trying to show the input(which user enters) and it's not working
Here's my code

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [messages,setMessages]=useState([]);

    console.log(messages);
    const sendMessage = (event)=>{
        setMessages([...messages,input]);
        setInput('');
    }

    return <div className="App">
        <h1>Messenger</h1>
        <input value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send Message</button>

        {
            messages.forEach(message =>{
                <p>{message}</p>
            })
        }
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot:

[image]

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
function App() {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [messages,setMessages]=useState([]);

    console.log(messages);
    const sendMessage = (event)=>{
        setMessages([...messages,input]);
        setInput('');
    }

    return <div className="App">
        <h1>Messenger</h1>
        <input value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send Message</button>

        {
            messages.map(message =>
                <p>{message}</p>
            )
        }
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Here is the working [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cloud-zvbkh?file=/src/App.js:0-620)

Comment: I used map() instead of forEach() but it's causing the same problem

Comment: most probably you were using ```map``` like ```messages.map(message =>{ <p>{message}</p>} )``` which returns nothing hence no output is shown on the screen.

Comment: :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `map()` which iterates over a list, transforms each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed members instead of `forEach()` which iterates over a list and applies some operation with side effects to each list member.

Method 1:

```
{
   messages.map((message) =>(
        <p>{message}</p>
    ))
}
```

Method 2:

```
{
   messages.map((message) =>{
     return <p>{message}</p>
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`.   `map` method will return a new array with the result of the callback function for each element in the array.

```
  { messages.map(message => <p>{message}</p>)}
```

Working demo: - https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-chatterjee-2eml6?file=/src/App.js